# What does sed 's/5//g' mean in this command line?

Tags: sed

Here is output of df -h.

```
[root@ip-10-0-7-225 ~]# df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/xvda1      8.0G  1.5G  6.6G  18% /
devtmpfs        478M     0  478M   0% /dev
tmpfs           496M     0  496M   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           496M   13M  484M   3% /run
tmpfs           496M     0  496M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs           100M     0  100M   0% /run/user/1000
```

So when running the following command, it said 18%.

```
[root@ip-10-0-7-225 ~]# df / | grep / | awk '{ print $5}'| sed 's/5//g'
```

18%

The point is if i change into the sed 's/5//g' part, the result 18% still came out.How is that?

Comment: Like the grep process, it is also redundant...

Comment: Why is that? Because if i remove the grep part, it would be like this.
root@ip-10-0-7-225 ~]# df | awk '{ print $5}'
Use%
18%
0%
0%
3%
0%
0%
0%

Comment: @TheOne Because it can all be done with: `awk '/^\// {print $5}'`...

Comment: @jasonwryan: Seems like it didn't work. My terminal hung when executing that command.

Comment: @TheOne Did you actually pipe `df /` to it?

Comment: @jasonwryan: Like this one? df / awk '/^\// {print $5}', right?

Comment: @TheOne No. `df / | awk '/^\// {print $5}'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sed 's/5//g'` here very likely means that a person typing this whole command line intended to strip the percent sign from the output, but missed the <kbd>Shift</kbd> and got `5` instead of `%`.

In its current form it instructs `sed` to remove `5` from the output, which does not make sense.

Answer (score 1):

grep - greps for the first line (contains /)

awk - prints out the 5th col (18%)

sed - substitutes 5 with nothing - it has no effect on the string from above (18%) as it doesn't contain a 5.